# Swift Framework Class to Swift Application

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Getting problem with adding my Swift Framework to Test Swift Application.

What i have:

Framework class code, Target Called 'Project':

```
public let Instance = Library()

   public class Library {
      public class var sharedInstance: Library {
         return Instance
      }
   /* SOME CODE */
   }
```

Than i build it and add Project.framework to Test Swift Application

Usage:

```
import Project

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    /* NOT WORKING 
    ERROR: Use of Unresolved Identifier 'Instance' */
    Instance.Setup("d573732b9f8b478d",apiKey: "3XmdIY=", enablePush: true)

    /* NOT WORKING TOO  
    ERROR: Use of Unresolved Identifier 'Library' */
    let lib = Library()
    return true
}
```

Functions public, DeviredData deleted, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Build Project Library, than get project.framework file from release folder and add as Embedded binary to Test Application

Comment: Because i don't want to share source code with customers. Sorry for noob questions, using Swift and programming under iOS for 5 days

Answer (score 0):

Answer was very easy:

Adding constructor function

```
public init(){

}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, making public constructor will help you, as per my knowledge default constructor has internal scope. It works for me.

```
public override init() {
    
}
```